# Plotly won't plot my time data when converted to a datetime object but will plot my unix epoch time array

Tags: javascript, python, css, plotly, data-science

****EDIT This must be done in vanilla JS or PYTHON****

I've been having some issues with my code - I am doing some data science applications and decided to build a web-gui for my team and some other engineering partners (I am not a classically trained CS guy). I have the following going on:

1.) I am managing my front and back end via flask

2.) My data scientist algo is in python

3.) My front end is written in JS, CSS, and html

My code has some proprietary things in it, so I cannot copy and paste it verbatim; however, I have done my best effort to replicate it on here (This code plots fine, but timedate data is not in human readable):

Python Code in Question (in my @routes):

```
@app.route("/backend", methods=["POST"]
def data_sci_alg
    rdy2plot = {}
    #stuf happens and I get a dictionary that looks like this after for looping, other than the time array, everything is 100%

    time = [1666202064.0, 1666202065.0, 1666202066.0, 1666202067.0, 1666202068.0, 1666202069.0, 1666202070.0, 1666202071.0, 1666202072.0, 1666202073.0]
    atn = ['N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN']
    alt = [10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000]
    cspeed = [1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200]
    data = {
            "aircraft_tail_number": atn,
            "time": time,
            "altitude": alt,
            "current_speed": cspeed,
        }    
    rdy2plot.update(data)
    return jsonify(rdy2plot)
```

print(type(time[0])) is a 'float'

JS Code in Question (in my static/index):

```
TESTER = document.getElementById('graph');

let data_update = []
function plot(data){
    var atn = data['atn']
    var time = data['time']
    var alt = data['alt']
    var cspeed = data['cspeed']
    data_update.push({x: time, y: alt, name: `${atn} Altitude`, type:"scatter"});
    data_update.push({x: time, y: cspeed, name: `${atn} Speed`, type:"scatter"});
    Plotly.react('graph', data_update, layout);
```

The concept of this, is that it loops through different aircraft parameters. via tail number, and plots them one at a time (This is why "data_update" is outside the function, so the graph updates as intended).

At this point, the data plots fine, but when I highlight the data in plotly, it shows my timestamp data, which is not really human readable.

I am using this (https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/date-format-and-time-series/) to try and see what plotly wants, and I am now attempting to plot the yyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS with the following code (does not plot!):

The output of python now looks like (I cannot paste exactly what I am doing here, but the output looks like below, via a print statement:

```
time = ['2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53']
```

```
print(type(time[0])) is a 'str'
```

JS console.log(time):

```
time = ['2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53', '2022-10-19 18:18:53']
```

Nothing is getting lost in translation, I don't understand why plotly is not taking this. Please help!

Sorry in advance for any typos or formatting issues, I had to transcribe this by hand - The main points are:

1.) It plots fine as of now, but the datetime information is in seconds since unix epoch (not human readable)

2.) When I transform my data into the above second list, nothing plots.

3.) My goal, regardless how it's accomplished, is human readable time data on my graph.

4.) Please be kind, I am not a trained CS guru.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you needed this in JS, but in Python you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

#provided data
df = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1666202064.0, 1666202065.0, 1666202066.0, 1666202067.0, 1666202068.0, 1666202069.0, 1666202070.0, 1666202071.0, 1666202072.0, 1666202073.0],
                   'atn':['N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN', 'N930NN'],
                   'alt':[10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 10000],
                   'cspeed':[1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200, 1200]})
#output
           time     atn    alt  cspeed
0  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
1  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
2  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
3  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
4  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
5  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
6  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
7  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
8  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200
9  1.666202e+09  N930NN  10000    1200

#convert unix time to datetime
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')

#output
                 time     atn    alt  cspeed
0 2022-10-19 17:54:24  N930NN  10000    1200
1 2022-10-19 17:54:25  N930NN  10000    1200
2 2022-10-19 17:54:26  N930NN  10000    1200
3 2022-10-19 17:54:27  N930NN  10000    1200
4 2022-10-19 17:54:28  N930NN  10000    1200
5 2022-10-19 17:54:29  N930NN  10000    1200
6 2022-10-19 17:54:30  N930NN  10000    1200
7 2022-10-19 17:54:31  N930NN  10000    1200
8 2022-10-19 17:54:32  N930NN  10000    1200
9 2022-10-19 17:54:33  N930NN  10000    1200

#plot data
fig = px.line(df,
      x='time',
      y=['alt', 'cspeed'])

fig.show()
```

[image: Figure]

Comment: I am so sorry amance, I meant to add I have to do this in vanilla python or JS. The it would take me months to get pandas on my system.

Comment: but maybe I should just pull the trigger and force my sys ad to get it, but I am also going to try and implement what you have going with your timestamp conversation, it is MUCH cleaner that what I have - I'll keep you posted.

Comment: I just realized you had `pd.to_datetime`, that's a bummer. I very much appreciate you commenting though.